# Рекурсивная замена кодировки файлов на OS X в Terminal

Tags: macos, find, iconv

OS X — Terminal
Необходимо рекурсивно пройтись папкам и для определённого типа файла изменить кодировку с WINDOWS-1251 на UTF-8.
Сделал выражение с помощью for:

```
for files in путь_к_папке_с_файлами/.*
    iconv -f WINDOWS-1251 -t UTF-8 "$files" >"$files-utf8"
```

Но в данном выражении необходимо после очередного выполнения менять ручками "путь_к_папке_с_файлами", что при большом количестве папок, не удобно.

Пытаюсь составить выражение с помощью find, но явно, что есть ошибка:

```
find путь_к_папке_с_файлами -type f -exec iconv -f WINDOWS-1251 -t UTF-8 '{}' > '{}.utf8' \;
```

или c уточнением типа файла:

```
find путь_к_папке_с_файлами -name '*.php' -exec iconv -f WINDOWS-1251 -t UTF-8 '{}' > '{}.utf8' \;
```

или

```
find путь_к_папке_с_файлами -name '*.php' -exec iconv -f WINDOWS-1251 -t UTF-8 '${} > '${}.utf8' \;
```

Вообщем, туплю ;)
Нужна помощь, заранее благодарен!

Comment: `find путь_к_папке_с_файлами -type f -exec iconv -f CP1251 -t UTF-8 -o {}.utf8 {}\;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find путь_к_папке_с_файлами -name '*.php' | perl -pe 'chomp;$_=qq[iconv -f WINDOWS-1251 -t UTF-8 "$_" >"$_-utf8"\n]'`

А потом, если понравилось, допишите `|sh`

Comment: Если автору помогло -- примите вопрос галочкой

Comment: Результат в терминале: `iconv -f WINDOWS-1251 -t UTF-8 "путь_к_папке_с_файлами/lng/en/adm/menu.php" >"путь_к_папке_с_файлами/lng/en/adm/menu.php-utf8"`, но в папке пусто! А потом добавил `|sh` и файлы появилились ;) Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: когда хочу проделать что-то хитрое -- генерирую команды, проверяю глазами, что не ерунда, следующим проходом применяю.